# ngTagsInput - Requirements

Tags: ng-tags-input

I am interested in using your ngTagsInput, but would need it to support older browsers. Can you quickly explain why older browsers would not work with it?

Best regards and many thanks in advance,
Oliver

Comment: Are you asking *why* or *what* older browsers won't work with ngTagsInput?

Comment: I am actually interested in both. As long as I don't know what older browsers are not support and why they won't work, I don't know how much effort it would take to get your solution to be ready for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

From the project's [GitHub page](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput#requirements):

> #### Requirements
>
> - AngularJS 1.3+
> - A modern browser (Chrome 31+, Firefox 29+, Safari 7+, Opera 12+, IE 10+)

That should answer the *what* part of your question. The *why* part is more complicated, because ngTagsInput has supported only modern browsers since day 1. I honestly don't know what parts of the code are incompatible with older browsers.

You might want to check out [this fork](https://github.com/Bessonov/ngTagsInput.ie8), though. Its goal is to provide basic support for IE8, and perhaps it can help you understand what needs to be done in order to support older browsers.